# Mysql integer not updating in query

Tags: mysql, integer

I have a php script that toggles a column variable from 0 to 1 and vice versa to indicate a locked record on the front end. The query (as shown by echo) is:

UPDATE 2112377_users SET Lock=0 WHERE userID='0071'

and the code doing the work is

```
if ($lock==1) $query="UPDATE ".$SQLusers." SET Lock=0 WHERE userID='".$userID."'";
else if ($lock==0) $query="UPDATE ".$SQLusers." SET Lock=1 WHERE userID='".$userID."'";
$mysqli->query($query);
```

The column structure is set to integer and length 1
The table name is correct as is the column name Lock
The record with that userID exists

However, the db isn't updating!

I've tried all combinations to get this to work but am stumped.

Maria

Comment: Well, setting a `$query` variable won't do much. Are you sending it to a MySQL wrapper function of some sort? I hope you're using PDO or MySQLi. If you are, are you outputting errors from your respective wrapper library? Please show your full code.

Comment: The call is as above. All the variables are passing to the script correctly.

Comment: Replace your `$mysqli->query()` line with `if (!$mysqli->query($query)) echo $mysqli->error;`. Also [see this documentation on reporting errors from MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php). You may need to check if the connection is working as well.

Comment: `lock` is a reserved word.  Use backticks around it.  Here is the list of reserved words:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reserved-words.html.